# Seeking help in understanding ngrx "selectors with props"

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to understand ngrx "selectors with props" [https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props]. There are two parts in the given links. The first part is clear to me and I could use it in my code. I could not understand the second part -

> Keep in mind that a selector only keeps the previous input arguments
>   in its cache. If you re-use this selector with another multiply
>   factor, the selector would always have to re-evaluate its value. This
>   is because it's receiving both of the multiply factors (e.g. one time
>   2, the other time 4). In order to correctly memoize the selector, wrap
>   the selector inside a factory function to create different instances
>   of the selector.
>
> The following is an example of using multiple counters differentiated
>   by id.

```
export const getCount = () =>
  createSelector(
    (state, props) => state.counter[props.id],
    (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
  );

ngOnInit() {
  this.counter2 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter2', multiply: 2 }));
  this.counter4 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 }));
  this.counter6 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter6', multiply: 6 }));
}
```

In above code, `(state, props) => state.counter[props.id]`, part I could not understand. Can somebody help in understanding `(state, props) => state.counter[props.id]` in combination with usage in `ngOnInit`?

It appears to me that `state.counter[props.id]` will return expected if `counter` state has properties with name as `id` i.e `counter2` or `counter4`.

The following link is also not explaining in details - https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

A short example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About the memoize cache in selector:

It returns the last cached value if it's subsequently called with same parameters.

```
export const getCount = () =>
  createSelector(
    (state, props) => state.counter[props.id],
    (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
  );

ngOnInit() {

// Calculate selector params (counter2, 2)  and return value
this.counter2 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter2', multiply: 2 })); 

// Calculate selector params (counter4, 4) and return value
this.counter4 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 }));

// Get Cached selector params (counter4, 4) and return value
this.counter5 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 })); 

// Calculate selector params (counter6, 6) and return value
this.counter6 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter6', multiply: 6 })); 

// Calculate selector params (counter4, 4) and return value
this.counter8 = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 }));
}
```

### About State

State will have shape we define in reducers that is created when AppModule is bootstrapping which will be update when Action is triggered.

```
export const initialState: State = {
  home: 0,
  away: 0,
};

const scoreboardReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.homeScore, state => ({ ...state, home: state.home + 1 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.awayScore, state => ({ ...state, away: state.away + 1 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.resetScore, state => ({ home: 0, away: 0 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.setScores, (state, { game }) => ({ home: game.home, away: game.away }))
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return scoreboardReducer(state, action);
}
```

Your assumption is right, state is passed on `selector` (the first parameter).

```
It appears to me that state.counter[props.id] will return expected if counter state has properties with name as id i.e counter2 or counter4.
```

Comment: Your answer clarifies my doubt. Thanks!